# Chrome loading cached files on localhost

Tags: google-chrome

I'm having this problem across 2 different machines now.

Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)
OSX 10.12.6

Chrome is persistently loading old cached files on `http://localhost:3000`. The only way I can stop it, is to use incognito. If I use `cmd + shift + r` it works for a single refresh, then goes back to the old files on reload.

I typically have the inspector up so I've tried ticked `disable cache`, that doesn't nothing. I've also tried deleting my cached files through chrome's settings, that does nothing.

Anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Finally realised what it was. A previous server I was running on that port had a manifest file and the appropriate service workers. It means that chrome was loading those cached files by default.

To fix it I went into developer tools > application > clear storage.

It now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Chrome was generating local overrides, for some reason. Before discovering this, I switched ports several times to get past the issue. Chrome had created a local override for my `index.html` file for each port. After deleting the local overrides, the actual from the server started coming through just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure is it a chrome cache? I mean, check if its really chrome cache getting the full of data in another way like curl, for example:

```
curl http://localhost:3000
```

If the content still not reloaded is not chrome problem but another think like your webserver.

If you are running Nginx don't worry it is Nginx configuration called sendfile and you can change it easily just doing this follow steps:

Step 1 - Open nginx configuration with your text editor(vim in my case)

```
vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Step 2 - Search the line with this text:

```
sendfile on;
```

Step 3 - Change to off

```
sendfile off;
```

Step 4 - Restart your nginx:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Note: If you are using virtual environment like Vagrant reload it

```
vagrant reload
```

Comment: curl returns the correct response, so does firefox/safari/opera. Chrome incognito returns the correct response. Just to put it in perspective, I'm not running any webserver. `ps aux` shows no webserver processes, this is purely a cache response. As stated in the question `cmd + shift + r` works once.

Comment: Seems confusing, if you're not using any webserver which service is listening on port 3000? I mean, if you're using localhost:3000 some service is started using this port right? Can you check which service is? It's angular?

Comment: it happens even when no service is running. curl can return "Connection refused" but chrome will still load a page. With the same favicon, and same html title in the tab.

Comment: Got it, I saw that you just cleared the storage data and fix it. I think this thread was great to help another people map common problems.